# XML Element Name from T in Generic Class

Tags: c#, xml, generics, inheritance

For a current project I am trying to make have a generic `XML` creator using the `XmlSerializer` class - I need a certain element in one of the classes to have the `ElementName` set based on the type of class that the creator is in in this context that is simple enough. Here is an example:

```
  public abstract class ElementTypeBase
  {
    public abstract string ElementName { get; }
  }
  public class ElementTypeA : ElementTypeBase
  {
    public override string ElementName
    {
      get { return "ElementA"; }
    }
  }
```

Then pass this to my `XML` object class which will be used for the `XmlSerializer` but I want the `ElementName` to be specific to the type.

```
  public class XMLObject<T> where T : ElementTypeBase
  {
    [XmlElement(Activator.CreateInstance<T>().ElementName)]
    public string SomeElement;
  }
```

I thought I would be able to do that but get:

> An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression
>   or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type

So I thought that I could `override ToString()` but this doesn't work, I was thinking of using constants but it feels dirty. Any other suggestions?

Comment: This sounds like a weird approach. Why use the `XmlSerializer` annotations if the XML structure is going to be dynamic anyway?

Comment: @millimoose This is one element in a whole host of structure which needs to be dynamic I could just create a class for each of the different types but trying to make it as generic as possible.

EDIT: When I say that I mean that the strucutre doesn't need to be dynamic for this XML but for one elemenet it does need to be because that single element can have different properties and obviously will need a different Element Name - the rest remains the same (Don't know how well I have explained that...)

Comment: The documentation mentions you can override [`IXmlSerializable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx) to customize XML serialisation, doing so on `ElementTypeBase` seems like the straightforward way to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that through the `XmlAttributeOverrides` class like shown below.
However, you'll need to cache the `XmlSerializer` instance and I wouldn't recommend this approach for your problem.

when you say that you have one element that is gonna be different for each inherited object, I'd suggest to put this element in the inherited class, not the generic one, and hard-code its `XmlElement.ElementName`.

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer =
            new XmlSerializer(typeof(XMLObject<MyElement>),
                XMLObject<MyElement>.Overrides);
        serializer.Serialize(Console.Out,
            new XMLObject<MyElement>() { SomeElement = "value" });
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public class XMLObject<T> where T : ElementTypeBase, new()
{
    public static XmlAttributeOverrides Overrides { get; private set; }
    static XMLObject()
    {
        Overrides = new XmlAttributeOverrides();
        Overrides.Add(typeof(XMLObject<T>), "SomeElement",
            new XmlAttributes
            {
                XmlElements =
                {
                    new XmlElementAttribute(new T().ElementName)
                }
            });
    }

    public string SomeElement { get; set; }
}
public abstract class ElementTypeBase
{
    public abstract string ElementName { get; }
}
public class MyElement : ElementTypeBase
{
    public override string ElementName
    {
        get { return "ElementA"; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You got me half way there by introducing me to the XmlAttributeOverrides, turns out it wasn't as complicated as my example made out but thanks anyway.

Comment: Right, as I outlined in the answer, even if it is feasible, you're question was pointing out more toward a design flaw rather than a technical problem. Glad you got it on your own.